# Getting error while implementing a simple sorting program in Mapreduce with zero reduce nodes

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I tried implementing a sorting program in mapreduce such that I have just the sorted output after the map phase where the sorting is done by the hadoop framework internally. For it, I tried to set the number of reduce tasks to zero as there wasnt any reduction required. Now when I tried executing the program, I kept on getting checksum 
error.. I am not able to figure out what's to be done next. Surely it's possible to run the program on my netbook as the sorting does work fine when I have set the reduce tasks to one.. Please help!!

---

For your reference, here's the entire code that I have written to perform the sorting:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;


public class word extends Configured implements Tool
{
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        private static IntWritable one=new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word=new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter report) throws IOException
        {
            String line=value.toString();
            StringTokenizer token=new StringTokenizer(line," .,?!");
            String wordToken=null;

            while(token.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                wordToken=token.nextToken();
                output.collect(new Text(wordToken), one);

            }
        }

    }

    public int run(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        //Configuration conf=getConf();
        JobConf job=new JobConf(word.class);
        job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(job);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        int exitCode=ToolRunner.run(new word(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);

    }
}
```

---

Here is the checksum error I got on executing this program:

```
12/03/25 10:26:42 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
12/03/25 10:26:43 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
12/03/25 10:26:43 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/03/25 10:26:44 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/03/25 10:26:45 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/03/25 10:26:45 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/03/25 10:26:45 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
12/03/25 10:26:45 INFO fs.FSInputChecker: Found checksum error: b[0, 26]=610a630a620a640a650a740a790a780a730a670a7a0a680a730a
org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/root/NetBeansProjects/projectAll/output/regionMulti/individual/part-00000 at 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.verifySum(FSInputChecker.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:158)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
12/03/25 10:26:45 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/root/NetBeansProjects/projectAll/output/regionMulti/individual/part-00000 at 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.verifySum(FSInputChecker.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:158)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
12/03/25 10:26:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/03/25 10:26:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/03/25 10:26:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
        at sortLog.run(sortLog.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at sortLog.main(sortLog.java:66)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: There will be no sort without reducers, even when the sort is done on the immediate map output ;)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut- Well, thanx for the reply but I dont think that we cannot have sorted output if we were to use no reducers. I also referred the book "Hadoop-The Definitive Guide" by Tom White and as mentioned on page 233, we certainly can have sorted output by setting reduce tasks to zero. :) Oh yes, I am working in the pseudo-distributed mode of hadoop installation so does that have anything to do with the problem I am facing? Thanx..

Comment: Even Tom can be wrong sometimes ;) See my answer.

Comment: Can you post the Checksum stack trace?

Comment: @Chris- Have posted the checksum error above. Do let me know if it regards my laptop's hardware configuration to give such error. I tried executing other sample sorting programs in hadoop-examples jar file and still got checksum error while running them..

Comment: Can you execute `hadoop fs -text file:/root/NetBeansProjects/projectAll/output/regionMulti/individual/part-00000` from the command line - does it checksum error too?

Comment: @ChrisWhite- Well, I dont understand this.. I could not execute the command for the same file above that you asked for as I deleted the folder and modified my code for something else today morning but I just changed the input path to the sorting program I have mentioned above and it worked just fine without any checksum error except that there was no sorting at all!! I think Thomas Jungblut was right.. But does this mean that there is no intermediate shuffling and sorting by hadoop framework if there are no reduce tasks at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So have a look at the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask` arround line 600 in 0.20.2.

```
  // get an output object
  if (job.getNumReduceTasks() == 0) {
     output =
       new NewDirectOutputCollector(taskContext, job, umbilical, reporter);
  } else {
    output = new NewOutputCollector(taskContext, job, umbilical, reporter);
  }
```

If you set the number of reduce tasks to zero it will be directly written to the output. The `NewOutputCollector` will use the so called `MapOutputBuffer` which does the spilling, sorting, combining and partitioning.

So when you set no reducer, no sort takes places, even if Tom White states this in the definitive guide.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem (checksum error concerning file part-00000 at 0). I solved it by renaming the file to any other name than -00000.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need at least one Reducer to make the internal sorting happen, than you can take the IdentityReducer.

You may also want to see this discussion:
[hadoop: difference between 0 reducer and identity reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630447/hadoop-difference-between-0-reducer-and-identity-reducer)